# BPMN gateways execution

Tags: gateway, bpmn

hello if I execute task1 once how many times will be executed task 4?

1. Exclusive (XOR) gateway
   [image]
2. Parallel (IN) gateway
   [image]
3. Event-Based gateway
   [image]
4. Inclusive  gateway
   [image]
5. Without gateway
   [image]

Comment: I know that XOR take only one path, parallel run all paths,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Once (either after task 2 or after task 3)
2. Once (after synchronization)
3. is syntactically wrong, as event based gateways must be followed by catching events (or receive tasks)
4. Once (after synchronization or after task 2 or after task 3)
5. Twice (because of implicit flow semantics: parallelization for outgoing flows. implicit xor semantics for incoming flows)

(I've intentionally neglected any run time errors which might happen before task 4, e.g. in case no condition attached to a data based gateway's outgoing sequence flow evaluates to true)

Comment: Thanks. And if I use XOR before task 2,3 and then I use parallel to join them, that means task 4 will be executed once, because of syncronization or it's syntactically wrong

Comment: Hi @Andrej. A parallel gateway to join pathes will just synchronize correctly as long as all incoming pathes are executed. So, what you describe is not syntactically wrong, because it's allowed to use the symbols in that combination, but it's semantically wrong, because you will cause a deadlock. Task 4 will never get executed and your process will hang at the parallel join forever.

Comment: @Andrej Correct! :-) Many greetings.